# An array of floats giving a numpy.ndarray object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is a followup question from [the one I posted a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577172/numpy-multiplying-int-with-float-seems-to-not-work). The problem I was having with multiplying int with float is fixed, thanks to user2357112 in the comments. However, it's come across another roadblock.

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

def gcd(m,n):
    if m < n:
        return gcd(n,m)
    return gcd(n,m%n)

def lcm(m,n):
    return (m*n)/(gcd(m,n))

def answer(m):
    tbd = []
    l = len(m)
    for i in range(l):
        s = sum(m[i])
        if s == 0:
            tbd.append(i)
            m[i][i] = 1
        else:
            for j in range(l):
                m[i][j] /= s
    tbd.sort(reverse=True)
    a = np.array(m)
    r = np.diag([1.0 for x in range(l)])
    for i in range(100):
        r *= a
    initial = [0 for x in range(l)]
    initial[0] = 1
    final = initial * r
    for i in tbd:
        del final[i]
    dens = []
    for i in range(len(final)):
        final[i] = final[i].limit_denominator()
        dens.append(final[i].denominator)
    lc = dens[0]
    for j in range(1,len(dens)):
        lc = lcm(lc,dens[j])
    for i in range(len(final)):
        final[i] = int(final[i] * lc)
    final.append(lc)
    return final

def main():
    print answer([[1,2],[2,1]])
    print answer([[0,1,0,0,0,1],[4,0,0,3,2,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]])

main()
```

Code in ideone: http://ideone.com/DO1otS

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "prog.py", line 48, in main
  File "prog.py", line 37, in answer
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'limit_denominator'
```

I am confused about why `final[i]` was recognized as a `numpy.ndarray` object. I thought that, since `final` is a 1-dimensional array, `final[i]` will therefore return the value (a `float`) within that array at index `i`. I'm not sure why that is not the case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `print final` gives me `[[  1.94032522e-48   0.00000000e+00]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]`. So you have a 2D array at that point, it doesn't matter that you index that (you then try to call `limit_denominator()` on a 1D array). Rather than turn instantly to another SO question, it's worth trying to debug via `print`.

Comment: As an aside, `fractions` already comes with a `gcd` implementations: `fractions.gcd`

Comment: There's a nice blog post about ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's quite easy to read and contains lots of helpful advise (although some aren't available in Python). Also helpful is the Python debugger [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) in case you encounter an (unexpected) exception. It contains lots of useful functions that make debugging much easier.

Comment: You import `Fraction` and then never use it. Just importing `Fraction` won't automatically give other numeric types a `limit_denominator` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question *"I am confused about why final[i] was recognized as a numpy.ndarray object."* In the following snippet of code

```
r = np.diag([1.0 for x in range(l)])
initial = [0 for x in range(l)]
final = initial * r
```

I skipped non-essential code. The code above shows that `r` is a `numpy.ndarray` and `initial` is a list. Then `final` is a product of a `numpy.ndarray` and a list. The result of this product is a `numpy.ndarray`.

What is also important is that `r` is an array of floats. Therefore `final` is also an array of floats and not fraction objects. Therefore you cannot call `limit_denominator()` on elements of `final`.

In addition, code such as:

```
for i in tbd:
    del final[i]
```

looks quite suspicious.

Comment: Let me see if I understood the issue correctly. So I would need to set `initial` as an array and then proceed with the multiplication (`final = initial * r`) as normal, then convert the `final` array into a list, then convert the numbers in the `final` list from `floats` into `Fractions`, so that I can get the denominators and continue with the problem?

Comment: @2012ssohn No, all I did was to answer to your direct question asked in the original post and show that your `final` array is a `numpy` array of floats.  I did not try to understand the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: @2012ssohn In [your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577172/numpy-multiplying-int-with-float-seems-to-not-work) you said: _"I am working on Google's "Doomsday Fuel" problem in Python 2.7 (it needs to be done in Python 2.7, hence the from `__future__` import division line) that uses NumPy, which admittedly I am not too familiar with."_ I would suggest you try to solve your problem using lists and fractions (if use of fractions is so important) and then attempt to convert your code to use `numpy` instead of "ordinary" Python lists once you get your algorithm working.